# How do I make jQuery notify like Twitter search?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I don't know what it's call. Example

http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23idontbelieveyou

When you click link above wait a few seconds. Then you will see a notify like this

```
102 more results since you started searching. Refresh to see them.
```

There any tutorial for this? Let me know how to make something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple, logically:

- A piece of Javascript checks back with the server every *n* seconds with a timestamp of the latest result it has.
- The server checks if any results are available newer than this timestamp and reports back how many there are.
- The Javascript displays this notification in the browser.

Comment: Okay let's say me, you and John.. Now I'm with `102 new results`, you with `40 new results`. What is the key to make the results will be different? Example now incoming 10 new results. Me will be `112` and you `50`.

Comment: @wow The key is that each client knows the **last tweet they have**. The script contacts the server and says *"The latest tweet I have is 2935862, is there anything newer than that?"*. Each client asks the server a different question and gets a customized answer.

Comment: @wow If you inspect what Twitter is doing, this is the URL the refresher script calls: `http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23idontbelieveyou&refresh=true&since_id=55877301660942340`. Notice the `since_id` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply polling a script via jquery or Ajax (same thing really)

```
// Untested, written here without syntax.
var timeSinceUpdate = <?php echo(time()); ?>;
$(document).ready(function(){    
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('queriesSince.php?searched=idontbelieveyou&timesinceupdate=' + timeSinceUpdate , function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(confirm('Add new Data to screen?'))
            {
                //Add Stuff to DOM and update the timeSinceUpdate from the data recieved.
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It would just sent an XHR to the server to see if any more tweets match the query.

If there are new matches, it will return the count and JavaScript updates the DOM to suit.